# Does PCl3 react with ester as it does with carboxylic acid to produce an acid halide?

Tags: organic-chemistry

I did not find it anywhere in a book but I do wonder if it might react.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does. All carboxylic acid derivatives undergo nucleophilic substitution reactions. So esters, acid anyhyrides, amides all on reacting with $\ce{PCl3}$ will give acid chlorides.

Comment: Please note that there is `mhchem` package enabled on chemistry.SE which allows you to type chemical formulas easier and more correctly via `$\ce{...}$` construction. For more info check out [How can I format math/chemistry expressions here?](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)

Comment: @andselisk I work a lot on mathematics.se so I have habits. Will surely take care from next time.

Comment: This answer is wrong.

Comment: @mithoron please provide a reference

Comment: This cannot work on amides, instead reactions leading to [imidoyl chlorides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imidoyl_chloride), [iminium chlorides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vilsmeier%E2%80%93Haack_reaction), or other products, can happen. Also _you_ should check out before answering and logic behind your answer isn't valid.

Comment: @Mithoron I am reading them from my textbook. Cengage's organic chemistry by KS Verma.

Comment: @Mithoron yes, the answerer may have been too broad, but still I would expect a reaction with esters to give the acid chloride.  Phosphorous will bond with oxygen over chlorine.